# Android Studio v31/values-v31.xml keeps generating color codes

Tags: android-studio

Im trying to fix this but idk why this v31 file keeps generating colors codes (see in SS) when I run my code, I keep deleting the color resources so that my code will run. just want to know how to stop it from doing that

Here is a screenshot of the error and the file
[image: Here is a screenshot of the error and the file]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this;

File --> Project Structure --> app(inside Modules) --> Dependencies -- Click "+" --> Library dependency --> Search "appcompat" and click "com.android.support:appcompat-v7(com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1)" --> click OK.

This should solve your error!

Answer (score 0):

Those color resources were added in Android 12 (API 31) so you'll want to compile with SDK v31 or newer

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
```